# How to Implement Join In Mysql to Fetch the Following Record

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am new to mysql I have three tables as follows

Table No 1 purchase

```
 +--------+-----------+--------+
 | UserID | productID |  traID |
 +--------+-----------+--------+
 | 525    |    2      |  602   |
 +--------+-----------+--------+
 | 525    |   1001    |  602   |
 +--------+-----------+--------+
 | 525    |   1002    |  602   |
 +--------+-----------+--------+
 | 525    |    1      |  602   |
 +--------+-----------+--------+
```

Table No 2 Deals

```
 +--------+-----------+
 | dealsid| deals_name|
 +--------+-----------+
 |   1    | First Deal|
 +--------+-----------+
 |   2    |Second Deal|
 +--------+-----------+
```

Table No 3 Productmaster

```
 +-----------+--------------+
 | productID | product_name |
 +-----------+--------------+
 | 1001      | HTML         |
 +-----------+--------------+
 | 1002      | JAVA         |
 +-----------+--------------+
```

I want the output of the above table as follows

(First Deal , Second Deal , HTML, JAVA)

The where Clause can be implemented to purchase.traID = 602 as I have posted on the above table.

Please help me with some mysql query.

Comment: There are no relation from Table 3 to Table 2. How they are related? Where are the foreign key?

Comment: You've tagged it both MYySQL and MySQLi, I assume you are using the later?

Comment: it seems Product_ID in first table is collection of dealsid OR productID. Is their any possibility product id in first table have id which present in second and third table(both the other table)?

Comment: The first table is the middle part of the rest of the tables. It means the user can purchase deals and product both so I want to get only the name of the deals and product purchased by the user.

Comment: Just Make sure all the record where  purchase.traID = 602

Comment: @emz MySQL is an RDBMS. mysqli is a PHP API. The two are not mutually exclusive!

Comment: @Strawberry The reason I asked was because it was ambiguous of which API he is using. When/if someone writes an answer in PHP for them.

Comment: @emz Well no one's going to do that because the mysql_ API is deprecated ;-)

Comment: @strawberry That is what I would've told him. Still seeing too many use it.

Comment: Any solution for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT pm.product_name , d.deals_name
FROM   purchase p, 
       deals d, 
       productmaster pm 
WHERE  p.productid = d.dealsid 
        OR p.productid = pm.productid 
       AND p.traID = 602;
```

you can use `SELECT distinct` instead of `select`
I will suggest to use Stored procedure: 
Find result from either table and get union of it as output

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_product_name
(
arg_traid int
)
BEGIN
    Select pm.product_name 
    from productmaster pm 
    inner join  purchase p
    on pm.productID = p.productID
    where p.traID = arg_traid
    Union
    Select d.deals_name
    from deals d
    inner join purchase p
    on d.dealsID = p.productID
    where p.traID = arg_traid

END
```

Comment: The data is coming repeatedly. and I don't know how to create stored procedure.

Comment: Can we put the condition in mysql i.e. if(pm.productID = p.productID) else if(d.dealsID = p.productID) inside the procedure

Comment: Means before the where condition to check that it is compared with which id products or deals

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   purchase p, 
       deals d, 
       productmaster pm 
WHERE  p.productid = d.dealsid 
        OR p.productid = pm.productid AND p.traID = 602;
```

Comment: can you write some procedure with condition that it will check one of it